# how to back propagate a change to a parent node?

Tags: terraform

I have a `null_resource.gateway_setup` that I'm unable to make idempotent - it can only run once.  Trying to run it more than once will result in an error.

Therefore, if I make a change to my `gateway_setup` block, I would like `terraform apply` to also trigger the `aws_instance.gateway` block to refresh.

Is this possible?  If so, how can I do this?

```
resource "aws_instance" "gateway" {
  ...
}

resource "null_resource" "gateway_setup" {
  depends_on = [ "aws_instance.gateway" ]
  ...
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
      connection {
        type  = "ssh"
        user  = "centos"
        host  = "${aws_instance.gateway.public_ip}"
      }
      inline = [ 
         # throw an error if gateway setup had already run on this instance
         # preferrably, instead of erroring, the instance should be destroyed and recreated
         "[ -f /etc/tf__null_resource__gateway_setup_complete ] && exit 1",

         # make some non-idempotent changes
         "./configure_gateway.sh",

         # flag that this instance is dirty
         "touch /etc/tf__null_resource__gateway_setup_complete",
      ]
  }
}
```

If I run `terraform apply` on a new environment, "null_resource.gateway_setup" should run ok.  If I make a change to my gateway setup logic, and run `terraform apply` again, before running "null_resource.gateway_setup" I would like the instance to be destroyed and recreated.

Comment: Can you share a more concrete example here? I'm struggling to see what you're trying to achieve as the question stands.

Comment: I've added some more info - does this help?

Comment: In that case why not run your script as user data? That way when you change it Terraform knows it needs to recreate the instance to apply out the change in startup behaviour.

Comment: If you want to add that as an answer, I'd glady up vote it :)